# SwiftUI AppDelegate didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken never called

Tags: swiftui, push, appdelegate

Simple problem that breaks the world:

SwiftUI, assigned the **@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor**, but the only delegate method that ever gets called is **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**.  I need the push notification token from the **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** delegate method.

How do I get this?  I've tried switching back to old lifecycle by using:

```
let window = UIWindow()
self.window = window
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(SessionStore()))
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

But this creates problems with @Observed objects in the app and crashes on people's devices.

Comment: could you show us the code for your `AppDelegate` and specifically the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` 
functions, together with how you use it in your `@main struct TestApp: App { ... }`